# How to override SpringBoot config external file to classpath file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-configuration

I would like override `SpringBoot` external's some config into classpath file., when I run jar by command line.

classpath -> application-config.yaml (Not application.yaml)

```
server:
  port: 8080
  servlet:
    contextPath: /myapp
test-message: this config no need to export as external config.
```

external -> D:/test/application-config-override.yaml

```
server:
  port: 9090
```

command

```
java -Dspring.config.location=classpath:application-config.yaml,file:///D:/test/application-config-override.yaml -jar myapp.jar
```

when I run above commend, the application is running 8080, contextPath is "myapp". My expected one is  `http://localhost:9090/myapp`

But, if I put all of **same config structure** of `application-config.yaml` into `application-config-override.yaml` as below

application-config-override.yaml

```
server:
  port: 9090
  servlet:
    contextPath: /yourapp
test-message: this config no need to export as external
```

Application is running 9090, contextPath is "yourapp".

How to override SpringBoot external some config into classpath file? I am using 2.5.4.

I don't want to export unnecessary some configs to external. I would like to marge and override by order.

Comment: Is it possible to change yml file names?

Comment: @ray It is possible to change. But. That will be more workload to change to for all project + all of CICD Pipeline .  We have over one hundred microservices. It is working fine at 2.1.x version

Comment: + 2.4.0 is working

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to provide both `spring.config.additional-location` and `spring.config.name` like this,

```
-Dspring.config.additional-location=D:///test/ -Dspring.config.name=application-config,application-config-override
```

Answer (score 1):

In Windows,

```
java -jar demo.jar --spring.config.additional-location=file:///C:/Data/demo/application-config-override.yaml --spring.config.name=application-config,application-config-override
```

In linux,

```
java -jar demo.jar --spring.config.additional-location=file:/home/user/config/application-config-override.yaml --spring.config.location=classpath:application-config.yaml
```

The above command would solve your need. Tested on Spring version 2.5.4

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SpringBoot why are you not using the SpringBoot naming conventions? If you name the files `application.yaml` then you will not have to run the jar specifying the locations of your config files as SpringBoot will automatically load them in (if they are in a default location).

Instead of `application-config.yaml` and `application-config-override.yaml` name both the internal and external files `application.yaml`.

Next, if you place the yaml file outside the jar it will automatically get read in by SpringBoot and do what you are trying to achieve.

Here is a test I ran:

internal `application.yaml` file:

```
value1: "internal" 
value2: "internal"
```

then in the application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

@Value("${value1}")
String val1;

@Value("${value2}")
String val2;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Value1: " + val1 + "\n" + "Value2: " + val2);
}

}
```

Then when I run this with no external config:

> java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

> INFO 6604 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication
> : Started DemoApplication in 1.611 seconds (JVM running for 2.118)
> **Value1: internal Value2: internal**

Then I place an external application.yaml in the same directory as the jar:

```
demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
application.yaml
```

Having value:

```
value1: "external"
```

Then the output is:

> java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>
> 2021-09-05 11:22:31.211  INFO 23540 --- [           main]
> com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in
> 1.552 seconds (JVM running for 2.101)
> **Value1: external Value2: internal**

So you can see the external `value1` overrides the internal `value1`

These configuration files are loading in a specific order and precedence.
From [SpringBoot Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html):

> Config data files are considered in the following order:
>
> - Application properties packaged inside your jar
> - Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar
> - Application properties outside of your packaged jar
> - Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is worked at 2.1.x verison. It is hard to change to for all project. We have over one hundred microservices.